# What is the best way to trigger change or input event in react js

Tags: reactjs

We use Backbone + ReactJS bundle to build a client-side app.
Heavily relying on notorious `valueLink` we propagate values directly to the model via own wrapper that supports ReactJS interface for two way binding.

Now we faced the problem:

We have `jquery.mask.js` plugin which formats input value programmatically thus it doesn't fire React events. All this leads to situation when model receives **unformatted** values from user input and **misses formatted ones** from plugin.

It seems that React has plenty of event handling strategies depending on browser. Is there any common way to trigger change event for particular DOM element so that React will hear it?

Comment:  React Github discussion: [Trigger simulated input value change for React 16](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11488)

Answer (score 360, accepted):

### For React ≥ 15.6.1

To trigger a React’s `change` event handler registered on an `input` element, you should set the `value` property on the element using the *native* setter before dispatching the event (if you set the `value` directly it will not work because it will use React’s *overridden* setter):

```js
const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
  window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
  'value').set;
nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, newValue);
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/catthr/pen/pddWzo)

Same solution for the `textarea` element by substituting `HTMLTextAreaElement`.

All credits go to [this Cypress contributor](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/647#issuecomment-335829482) and [his solution](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/commit/4a56ca83b3b6e19ec57d10a8160f54f513e8f8ec).

### For React ≤ 15.6.0

To trigger a React’s `change` event handler registered on an `input` element, you should set the `value` property on the element and set the `simulated` property on the event (React specific) before dispatching the event:

```js
input.value = newValue;
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
event.simulated = true;
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/catthr/pen/PKXzLQ)

To understand why `simulated` is needed, I found [this comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/536#issuecomment-308739206) very helpful:

> The input logic in React now dedupe's change events so they don't fire more than once per value. It listens for both browser `onChange`/`onInput` events as well as `set`s on the DOM node `value` prop (when you update the value via javascript). This has the side effect of meaning that if you update the input's value manually `input.value = 'foo'` then dispatch a `ChangeEvent` with `{ target: input }` React will register both the `set` and the event, see it's value is still `'foo', consider it a duplicate event and swallow it.
>
> This works fine in normal cases because a "real" browser initiated event doesn't trigger `set`s on the `element.value`. You can bail out of this logic secretly by tagging the event you trigger with a `simulated` flag and react will always fire the event. https://github.com/jquense/react/blob/9a93af4411a8e880bbc05392ccf2b195c97502d1/src/renderers/dom/client/eventPlugins/ChangeEventPlugin.js#L128

Comment: Thanks this did work from react-dom ^15.6.0. But it seems post React 16.0 this has stopped working. Any idea on the alternative to using simulated flag to trigger the change events?

Comment: Believe there is a point here which would give the hint: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#breaking-changes Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Qwerty I updated my answer, may be it'll work for you

Comment: and what abou button onClick? what sould be done to trigger this kind of event?

Comment: @Bender you just call native [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method on element

Comment: @Grin sure, thank you, some times I'm just overcomplicating

Comment: @Grin for me this is working if I use  nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, "01.06.2019"); but I really want to use the value from the input itself: nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, input.value); But this is not calling the onChange of react... Do You know why this is?

Comment: @G43beli probably because old and new values are equal. If you need to use current value you can save it to variable and reset value on input like so `var curValue = input.value; input.value = ''; nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, curValue);` and then dispatch input event

Comment: Worked for me on an angular site as well, Thanks!

Comment: For those who are wondering about what is the variable `input`, it can be a `ref` so if you have assigned like `<input ref={inputRef} />` then `input` variable will be `inputRef.current`.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: Illegal invocation` on `textarea` elements.
Juste changing `window.HTMLInputElement` by `window.HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype` did the tricks. Thank you

Comment: This works for MOBX as well in 2023

Answer (score 73):

At least on text inputs, it appears that `onChange` is listening for input events:

```js
var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Depends on the browser version. IE8 doesn't support input event. And ie9 doesn't fire input event when u remove characters from the textbox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: `Event` is not support IE [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

Comment: IE8 [is no longer supported](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/12/discontinuing-ie8-support.html) by React.  For IE9, you may be able to use something like `var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');  event.initCustomEvent('input', true, false, { });`, but I don't have a IE9 VM handy.

Comment: @Michael I'm trying your code on IE11 and it's not working on reactjs input fields. It does work on normal HTML inputs. It also works on Edge.
`var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    evt.initCustomEvent('input', true, false, { });
    document.getElementById('description').value = 'I changed description';
    document.getElementById('description').dispatchEvent(evt);`

Comment: This does not work for MOBX

Answer (score 27):

Expanding on the answer from Grin/Dan Abramov, this works across multiple input types. Tested in React >= 15.5

```
const inputTypes = [
    window.HTMLInputElement,
    window.HTMLSelectElement,
    window.HTMLTextAreaElement,
];

export const triggerInputChange = (node, value = '') => {

    // only process the change on elements we know have a value setter in their constructor
    if ( inputTypes.indexOf(node.__proto__.constructor) >-1 ) {

        const setValue = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(node.__proto__, 'value').set;
        const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });

        setValue.call(node, value);
        node.dispatchEvent(event);

    }

};
```

Comment: Does not work for select elements. You need 'change' instead of 'input' for the event.

Comment: Just so people are aware, `__proto__` is deprecated according to the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

You can use Object.getPrototypeOf(node). constructor instead :)

Comment: Can't make this work on a page I try to automate. Not sure which version of React they're using.

Answer (score 21):

I know this answer comes a little late but I recently faced a similar problem.  I wanted to trigger an event on a nested component.  I had a list with radio and check box type widgets (they were divs that behaved like checkboxes and/or radio buttons) and in some other place in the application, if someone closed a toolbox, I needed to uncheck one.

I found a pretty simple solution, not sure if this is best practice but it works.

```
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
 'view': window, 
 'bubbles': true, 
 'cancelable': false
});
var node = document.getElementById('nodeMyComponentsEventIsConnectedTo');
node.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This triggered the click event on the domNode and my handler attached via react was indeed called so it behaves like I would expect if someone clicked on the element.  I have not tested onChange but it should work, and not sure how this will fair in really old versions of IE but I believe the MouseEvent is supported in at least IE9 and up.

I eventually moved away from this for my particular use case because my component was very small (only a part of my application used react since i'm still learning it) and I could achieve the same thing another way without getting references to dom nodes.

UPDATE:

As others have stated in the comments, it is better to use `this.refs.refname` to get a reference to a dom node. In this case, refname is the ref you attached to your component via `<MyComponent ref='refname' />`.

Comment: Instead of ID, you can use the `React.findDOMNode` function. http://goo.gl/RqccrA

Comment: >Instead of ID, you can use the React.findDOMNode function. 
Or add a `ref` to your element then use `this.ref.refName.dispatchEvent`

Comment: Framework has most likely changed since, its this.ref**s**.refname

Comment: String refs are considered legacy now and will be deprecated in the future. Callback refs are the preferred method to keep track of the DOM node.

Answer (score 9):

You can simulate events using [ReactTestUtils](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) but that's designed for unit testing.

I'd recommend not using valueLink for this case and simply listening to change events fired by the plugin and updating the input's state in response. The two-way binding utils more as a demo than anything else; they're included in addons only to emphasize the fact that pure two-way binding isn't appropriate for most applications and that you usually need more application logic to describe the interactions in your app.

Comment: I was afraid that answer will be something like that (.
Problem is that React is too strict with send/receive workflow. In particular one must specify onChange handler to be able to react on user input,no other way except uncontrolled state which is kind of over boilerplate to me.In my case I should declare this handler only to follow the rules, while relevant input will come from onchange event triggered by jquery. React really lacks idea of extending  send/receive endpoints with user declared code

Comment: And... in case you want to use ReactTestUtils...
`ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.fieldRef))`

Answer (score 9):

For `HTMLSelectElement`, i.e. `<select>`

```js
var element = document.getElementById("element-id");
var trigger = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
  window.HTMLSelectElement.prototype,
  "value"
).set;
trigger.call(element, 4); // 4 is the select option's value we want to set
var event = new Event("change", { bubbles: true });
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I've got the full set - select, text & radio (for my job applications!).

Answer (score 8):

A working solution can depend a bit on the implementation of the `onChange` function you're trying to trigger. Something that worked for me was to reach into the react props attached to the DOM element and call the function directly.

I created a helper function to grab the react props since they're suffixed with a hash like `.__reactProps$fdb7odfwyz`

*It's probably not the most robust but it's good to know it's an option.*

```
function getReactProps(el) {
  const keys = Object.keys(el);
  const propKey = keys.find(key => key.includes('reactProps'));
  return el[propKey];
}

const el = document.querySelector('XX');
getReactProps(el).onChange({ target: { value: id }  });
```

Since the onChange function was only using `target.value` I could pass a simple object to `onChange` to trigger my change.

---

This method can also help with stubborn react owned DOM elements that are listing for `onMouseDown` and do not respond to `.click()` like you'd expect.

```
getReactProps(el).onMouseDown(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: This combined with a local override (isTrusted) worked for me.

Comment: Finally something that works for react-tag-input's input box!

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon the same issue today. While there is default support for the `'click', 'focus', 'blur'` events out of the box in JavaScript, other useful events such as `'change', 'input'` are not implemented (yet).

I came up with this generic solution and refactored the code based on the accepted answers.

```
export const triggerNativeEventFor = (elm, { event, ...valueObj }) => {
  if (!(elm instanceof Element)) {
    throw new Error(`Expected an Element but received ${elm} instead!`);
  }

  const [prop, value] = Object.entries(valueObj)[0] ?? [];
  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(elm.__proto__, prop);

  desc?.set?.call(elm, value);
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event(event, { bubbles: true }));
};
```

**How does it work?**

```
triggerNativeEventFor(inputRef.current, { event: 'input', value: '' });
```

Any 2nd property you pass after the `'event'` key-value pair, it will be taken into account and the rest will be ignored/discarded.
This is purposedfully written like this in order not to clutter arguments definition of the helper function.
The reason as to why not default to get descriptor for `'value'` only is that for instance, if you have a native checkbox `<input type="checkbox" />`, than it doesn't have a value rather a `'checked'` prop/attribute. Then you can pass your desired check state as follows:

```
triggerNativeEventFor(checkBoxRef.current, { event: 'input', checked: false });
```

Comment: Did not work for react-tag-input's input box.

Answer (score 4):

I found this on React's Github issues:  Works like a charm (v15.6.2)

Here is how I implemented to a Text input:

```
changeInputValue = newValue => {

    const e = new Event('input', { bubbles: true })
    const input = document.querySelector('input[name=' + this.props.name + ']')
    console.log('input', input)
    this.setNativeValue(input, newValue)
    input.dispatchEvent(e)
  }

  setNativeValue (element, value) {
    const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'value').set
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(element)
    const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
      prototype,
      'value'
    ).set

    if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
      prototypeValueSetter.call(element, value)
    } else {
      valueSetter.call(element, value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the textbox value is the same as the value you are passing to setNativeValue

Answer (score 3):

Triggering change events on arbitrary elements creates dependencies between components which are hard to reason about. It's better to stick with React's one-way data flow.

There is no simple snippet to trigger React's change event. The logic is implemented in ChangeEventPlugin.js and there are different code branches for different input types and browsers. Moreover, the implementation details vary across versions of React.

I have built [react-trigger-change](https://github.com/vitalyq/react-trigger-change) that does the thing, but it is intended to be used for testing, not as a production dependency:

```js
let node;
ReactDOM.render(
  <input
    onChange={() => console.log('changed')}
    ref={(input) => { node = input; }}
  />,
  mountNode
);

reactTriggerChange(node); // 'changed' is logged
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/vitalyq/pen/PmYGgY?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

The Event type `input` did not work for me on `<select>` but changing it to `change` works

```
useEffect(() => {
    var event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
    selectRef.current.dispatchEvent(event); // ref to the select control
}, [props.items]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This ugly solution is what worked for me:

```js
let ev = new CustomEvent('change', { bubbles: true });
Object.defineProperty(ev, 'target', {writable: false, value: inpt });
Object.defineProperty(ev, 'currentTarget', {writable: false, value: inpt });
const rHandle = Object.keys(inpt).find(k => k.startsWith("__reactEventHandlers"))
inpt[rHandle].onChange(ev);
```

Answer (score 0):

well since we use functions to handle an onchange event, we can do it like this:

```
class Form extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
  this.state = { password: '' }
 }

 aForceChange() {
  // something happened and a passwordChange
  // needs to be triggered!!

  // simple, just call the onChange handler
  this.handlePasswordChange('my password');
 }

 handlePasswordChange(value) {
 // do something
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <input type="text" value={this.state.password} onChange={changeEvent => this.handlePasswordChange(changeEvent.target.value)} />
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This (typescript) worked for me with React:

```
export function updateInputText(input: HTMLInputElement, value: string) {
  const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    input.constructor.prototype,
    "value"
  )!.set!;
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, value);

  const e = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
  input.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Backbone and React, I'd recommend one of the following,

- [Backbone.React.Component](https://github.com/magalhas/backbone-react-component)
- [react.backbone](https://github.com/clayallsopp/react.backbone)

They both help integrate Backbone models and collections with React views. You can use Backbone events just like you do with Backbone views. I've dabbled in both and didn't see much of a difference except one is a mixin and the other changes `React.createClass` to `React.createBackboneClass`.

Comment: Please, be careful with those "event-driven" bridges between react and backbone
First plugin uses setProps disregard of component mount level. It's a mistake.
Second heavily relies on forceUpdate and minds that only one model could be assigned for a component, which is not common situation.
More over, if u share model across complex UI with react components and have had forgotten to unsubscribe from useless update events that cause forceUpdate, then you can fall into recursive rendering, be aware about that.