# Use JavaScript to set value of textbox when .value and events don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to set a value for the textbox on a PayPal Giving Fund [donation page](https://www.paypal.com/fundraiser/charity/196655) and am thoroughly stumped.

Here's what I've tried:

**Setting `input.value`**

From Chrome devtools, if I run the following JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('nemo_inputAmount').value = '1'
```

The value '1' appears in the textbox, but when I click the "Donate Now" button, the value is cleared and the form does not submit.

**Sending events**

I used Chrome devtools to monitor all of the events when I tabbed into the textbox, typed the value '1', and tabbed out.

Then I recreated each of those events using the code below. The value '1' does not even appear in the textbox using this approach. I have tried every combination and style of dispatching events that I can think of.

```
function textEvent(text) {
  let textEvent = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
  textEvent.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, text);
  return textEvent;
}

function setDonationAmount(amount) {
  let amountInput = document.querySelector('input#nemo_inputAmount');

  if (amountInput) {
    console.log('Setting amount to', amount)

    const events = [
      new FocusEvent('focus', {
        composed: true
      }),
      new Event('select', {
        bubbles: true
      }),
      new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        composed: true,
        code: 'Digit1',
        key: '1',
        keyCode: 49,
        which: 49
      }),
      new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        composed: true,
        code: 'Digit1',
        key: '1',
        keyCode: 49,
        which: 49
      }),
      textEvent('1'),
      new Event('input', {
        bubbles: true
      }),
      new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        composed: true,
        code: 'Digit1',
        key: '1',
        keyCode: 49,
        which: 49
      }),
      new Event('change', {
        bubbles: true
      }),
      new FocusEvent('blur', {
        composed: true
      })
    ]

    events.forEach(function(event) {
      amountInput.dispatchEvent(event);
    })
  }
}

setDonationAmount('1');
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do this in pure JavaScript. I'm completely baffled why neither of the solutions above work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are all the preconditions of form submission met? Missing any required fields?

Comment: Try document.execCommand [as shown here](//stackoverflow.com/a/42375168).

Comment: @JaredSmith Aside from some buttons that set fixed donation amounts, this textbox is the only form element on the page.

Comment: @wOxxOm That works! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it! :)

Comment: I doubt I should add an identical answer. AFAIK in such cases the question is considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input is part of a React component. I was able to find this by searching the source for the ID of the input (`nemo_inputAmount`). This search took me to the render function for the component. Here's the relevant section of it:

```
_react2.default.createElement('input', {
  type: 'text',
  id: 'nemo_inputAmount',
  className: inputBoxStyling,
  onChange: this.handleInputChange,
  onFocus: this.handleInputFocus,
  value: this.state.inputAmount,
  autoComplete: 'off',
  placeholder: 'Other Amount',
  required: true
}),
```

You can see the event handlers on it: `onChange` and `onFocus`. The handlers are defined earlier on. Here are the snippets:

```
handleInputChange: function handleInputChange(event) {

  var value = event.target.value;
  var input = (0, _parseAmount2.default)(value);
  if (input === undefined) {
    return this.invalid();
  }

  this.setState({
    inputAmount: input
  });
},

handleInputFocus: function handleInputFocus() {
  this.setState({
    selectedAmount: '',
    radioBtnClicked: false,
    clickedIndex: -1
  });
},
```

You can see that when the input changes it changes the `inputAmount` in the store to the new amount. If you look back to the `createElement` function you can see the `inputAmount` in the store is bound to the `value` attribute of the `input`.

```
  value: this.state.inputAmount,
```

This means the value of the input is set when the event handler is only run when the relevant event is fired.

Setting the `value` attribute programmatically **does not** fire the event, which is why your input kept clearing because the store wasn't updated so it was still empty.

To make it work you will need this:

```
const input = document.getElementById('nemo_inputAmount');
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
input.value = '1';
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This part creates a new `input` event, which is the event that  `handleInputChange` actually reacts to – I haven't looked at the React source to confirm, this statement is based on observations and this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056122/3050293).

```
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
```

This part then dispatches the event.

```
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Ah, it's like a combination of the two things I've tried! Extracting the `input` event from my second attempt and combining that with my first attempt totally works!

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing that worked for me, works in Edge:

```
function setNativeValue(element, value) {
  const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'value').set;
  const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(element);
  const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, 'value').set;
  
  if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
    prototypeValueSetter.call(element, value);
  } else {
    valueSetter.call(element, value);
  }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
setNativeValue(textarea, 'some text');
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

Obtained from here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-314441175

Comment: Works in Chrome 96. Nov/2021.