# How to correctly change value of reactjs input on IE through DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to change the value of a reactjs input field on Internet Explorer via DOM manipulation without access to the source code.

```
document.getElementById('description').value = 'I changed description';
```

The "description" field is a simple HTML textarea with reactjs.
Reading other questions here, (that frustratingly I'm not able to comment on them) I found that to actually change the value, reactjs require to trigger an input event on the field.

Seen here: [What is the best way to trigger onchange event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js/31056122#31056122)

The solution is to send the following input event after the change:

```
var evt = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This code works on Chrome and Firefox, but Internet Explorer doesn't support new Event().

There is a polyfill for it:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
evt.initCustomEvent('input', true, false, { });
elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

For some reason this is not working on IE11 just on Edge. When I say it's not working, I mean it's not working for reactjs fields, it will work on normal HTML5 fields though.

Finally, how can I correctly change the value of a reactjs input field on IE11 through DOM ? It has to be on IE, other browsers I already know how to.