# React form's onChange not triggered on value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React dom 16.4.0.

There is a form with an input inside. Changing input's value using programatically doesn't trigger form's `onChange`:

```
class Bar extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  private foo: any;

  constructor(props: IProps, state: IState) {
    super(props);
    ..
    this.foo = React.createRef();
    ..

<form>
  ..
  <input ref={this.foo} type="text" />

..
private handleClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
  const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': false,
    'view': window,
  });
  this.foo.current.dispatchEvent(event); <- doesn't trigger form's onChange
```

Found [this topic](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8971) on React official GitHub. Also found this StackOverflow topic with [lots of similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js/31056122) (none of it work).

So any idea how to actually make input element trigger onChange?

**IMPORTANT:** I am actually trying to make [Bootstrap button-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) work. Since the radio got hidden and controlled using a span click, the onChange is not triggered.

Comment: AFAIK `event` is a reserved word. Try renaming your `const event` to smth. like `customEv` and try again