# React - Cannot dispatch onChange event from input text element programatically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two components: `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`.

The `ChildComponent` has an `input[type="text"]` element that when it changes its text that event is propagated to the `ParentComponent` through the event `change` and the `onChange` listener.

The code below is a simplification of a bigger problem, that's why you will see some requirements highlighted there.

**My problem is** that I need to trigger the `change` event inside the function: `handleClick`. I did some experiments with no luck.

Here you have the **code sandbox** you can experiment with (please provide a fork with your approach):

https://codesandbox.io/s/wqw49j5krw

Here you have the code:

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Peter"
    };
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    let target = event.target;
    let value = target.value;
    this.setState({
      name: value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
        <span>Hello</span>&nbsp;
        <span>{this.state.name}!</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value
    };
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    const name = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ value: name });
    if (this.props.onChange !== undefined) {
      this.props.onChange(event);
    }
  };
  handleClick = name => {
    const inputName = this.refs.name;
    console.log('Name before being changed: ' + inputName.value); // this works
    // PROBABLY HERE IS WHERE THE CODE NEEDS TO BE MODIFIED
    this.setState({ value: name });
    var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    inputName.dispatchEvent(event); // this doesn't propagate the event to the parent
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {"Your name: "}
        <input type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          ref="name"
        />
        {/* requirement: the following 2 lines cannot be modified */}
        <button onClick={e => { this.handleClick("Steve"); }}>Steve</button>
        <button onClick={e => { this.handleClick("Emily"); }}>Emily</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Your sandbox link is working, what you want to do actually?

Comment: when you click the buttons: `Steve` / `Emily` the name on the `ParentComponent` doesn't get updated

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js

Comment: @Justcode the parent component don't get the text underneath updated when on the child component you click the buttons: `Steve` / `Emily`. I need the event gets passed to the parent component.

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G I tried the approach there but didn't work, here is my try: https://codesandbox.io/s/1q3mpkmrnl. Could you provide some fork of the code on codesandbox.io?

Comment: @Viewsonic You are trying to get the `event.target` instead, you can work directly with the value. you can pass only the value to the function, so that it can be called from anywhere without passing the event, only the value. Is it feasible in your case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the track of the input change,

> Because React tracks when you set the value property on an input to
>   keep track of the node's value. When you dispatch a change event, it
>   checks it's last value against the current value and if they're the
>   same it does not call any event handlers (as no change has taken place
>   as far as react is concerned). So we have to set the value in a way
>   that React's value setter function will not be called, which is where
>   the setNativeValue comes into play.

Here you are setting the state instead of changing the input's value directly so, it will not get the updated value when you are dispatching the event. and if you write value directly like `input.value` it can not track the changes of the input.

so, you should set the value and dispatch the event, this way you can have the updated value when event is dispatched.

Here is the link of the [reference](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/pull/153) and [another](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135), there are other ways too, to fire the change event.

Here is the function you need to set the property so that react can track the changes,

```
  handleClick = name => {
    const inputName = this.refs.name;
    console.log("Name before being changed: " + inputName.value); // this works

    var event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });

    this.setNativeValue(inputName, name);
    inputName.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  setNativeValue = (element, value) => {
    const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, "value").set;
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(element);
    const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
      prototype,
      "value"
    ).set;

    if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
      prototypeValueSetter.call(element, value);
    } else {
      valueSetter.call(element, value);
    }
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/104vmo56v3)

Answer (score 0):

You can include an onClick function to the parent component to change the state and pass it onto the child component. In the child component you can call the onClick method passed down via props and pass the name when button is clicked.

You can find the example code in the link provided below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0n1j2rrx7

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code like that:
in handleChange function of parentComponent I changed the parameter to value from event.
In childComponent I added the function call below to handleClick function:

```
 this.props.onChange(name);
```

Why I did these changes because, you call your parentComponent's handleChange function from your childComponent' s onChange function. 
When you click the button, it calls handleClick function. In handleClick function it calls property onChange function. The props.onChange function calls handleChange function of parent component.
handleClick -> this.props.onChange(name) -> this.handleChange(name)
I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to change the parent text like `Hello Peter` when you click the button from child component.

Check my codesandbox : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yj3lwx7r0v)

**Changes:**

In child component, pass a props like `this.props.onClick(name);`

In parent, get it like

```
  handleClick = name => {
    this.setState({
      name
    });
  };
```

Hope this is will help you.