# Value is not updating on the input entry in JS in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to put a new value in a form by implementing this script.

```
document.querySelector('src').value = 'val';
```

It changes the text in text field but when I click enter after, this script returned the previous value. It does not change a new value. 
When I do the same manually the value is changing.

Comment: What is `src` here?

Comment: Is this react? You might want to set the value on the form element to state and update the state instead

Comment: Post your element where you want to add value.

Comment: refer to this question. from React  >=15.6 because the setter .value= is not working as we wanted as React library overrides the input value setter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-change-or-input-event-in-react-js

Answer (score 1):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) take string as argument.

You should do this,

```
document.querySelector('src').value = 'val';   //for src tag, I don't think of any `src` tag in HTML
document.querySelector('#src').value = 'val';  //for src as id
document.querySelector('.src').value = 'val';  //for src as class
```

Comment: yes, I put string there. It inputs my value in a textfield, but value doesn't change. I can see it in console.

Comment: So you have element with `src` tag? Where you want to add value?

Comment: Post your element where you want to add value.

Comment: my value is 'test' <input maxlength=20 class=testClass value="test">, I am trying to change it by implementing the script above. It changes the text in a textfield but it doesn't change the value itsels. But when I change it manually it changes the value.

Comment: Do this - document.querySelector('.testClass').value = 'val';

Comment: the problem is not in this value, it finds it and puts text there but it doesn't change the value when I click enter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197472/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-nikolai).

Comment: I have also experienced this problem. same issue no matter if you go back to the parent and then to the child to re-register as a class. It will always revert and just add text.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this via the state. React re-renders the components on change of state which is why you wanna change state and in turn cause the input entry to change.

Comment: How to do it via the state?