# Imitate user input in a React controlled input

Tags: reactjs

I want to automate a React app by filling forms using a js snippet, but I cannot make it to call the onChange handler. 
I emit the change event with the following code:

```
const event = new Event("change", 
{ 
    bubbles: true, 
    cancelable: true, 
    view: window,
    target: { value: "new value"}
});
const element = document.querySelector("#inp");
element.value = "new value";
const cancelled = element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

but the React refuses to change the value of the text input.

The complete example is here https://jsfiddle.net/gLysoa8v/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a bit I found the solution in this question: [What is the best way to trigger onchange event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js#46012210)

```
var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, 'react 16 value');

var ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
```