# Can't seem to simulate a keypress in Javascript that 'unlocks' & clicks the Reddit 'Post' button?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

[image: the element's event listeners][image]I've tried the following & they do not work:

```
document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'70'}));

document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]")..dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'70'}));


document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").value = 'titleTextProgramaticallyInput'[![jav][1]][1]
```

The title element is preventing me from programatically clicking 'Post'

URL:
https://www.reddit.com/user/**yourUsername**/submit

[image]

Comment: Try to send an `input` event to that `<input/>`.

Comment: Would you provide example code?

e.g. document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").oninput(...)

Comment: `.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))`

Comment: tried this: document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))

Comment: No luck. Wrong target element? Wrong event?

Comment: Try an `insertText`, eg: `var el = document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]"); el.focus(); el.ownerDocument.execCommand('insertText', false, 'titleTextProgramaticallyInput')`.

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Check what events are registered to that element, in Chrome you can use `getEventListeners(document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]"))` from the console.

Comment: I posted a picture of it's event listeners. How would I use that info?

Comment: Probably one of those listeners' callback function changes the number in the `0/300` label and enables the button. There is a listener for `input`, the `.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))` should have triggered that. Another thing to try will be simulating a clipboard paste.

Comment: I tried ```document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").value = 'title'; document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))``` again, still no luck.

Comment: Also tried ```document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]").addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
}); ``` to simulate paste, no luck. Is there a alternative way to simulate pasting more likely to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reddit is using react, so these input fields are hidden behind layers of complexity. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012210/980423).

Using the instructions from there you can light up the post button by triggering it's actual `set` method from the textArea prototype:

```
var titleElement = document.querySelector("[placeholder=Title]");
var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype, "value").set;
nativeInputValueSetter.call(titleElement, 'react 16 value');

var triggerUpdateEvent = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
titleElement.dispatchEvent(triggerUpdateEvent);
```

Comment: Great insight. I can light it up with this code but cannot `titleElement.click()` it.

Comment: Presumably the same problem - need to call the prototype method on the input button.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, worked fine for me.

```document.querySelector("._2JBsHFobuapzGwpHQjrDlD").click();``` where that class selects the button.

I don't think you mean you are trying to click the title, right?

Comment: You did it dude! worked. (clicked the wrong element in my initial comment, oops)