# Simulate change event to enter text into react textarea with vanilla js script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I know this is not "the react way," or any other version of ideal. But circumstances are beyond my control and I need to find a work around or "hack". That being said....

I am looking for a way to programmatically enter text content into a `<textarea>` element that is rendered as part of a react component. The catch is I need to do this from outside of the react app. The react app was written, compiled, minified, and delivered by someone else.

The `<textarea>` has an `id` attr assigned, so I can query it and set its `.value` easily enough. **However my real aim is to effect the *state* of the react application**, that is to say, to use the text area's bound `onChange` handler to get my string into the state of the component which renders the text area.

So far I have tried to First: Set the value of the `<textarea>`. Second: trigger a "change" event. But so far this does not fire the `onChange` callback.

To give you an idea of what I am actually talking about I created a [minimal example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-inject-text-to-textarea?file=index.js) of this challenge.

Here's the code from that stackblitz:

**The react part.** 
This represents the react app that I have no control over.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      message: "" //I would like this be the value of what I place into the text area
    }
  }

  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({
      message: e.target.value
    }, ()=>{ console.log(this.state) })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <textarea 
          id="text-area-in-react" 
          onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**And then the non-react or external part.** 
In this case placed in a `<script>` tag in index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
  setTimeout(()=>{
    const textarea = document.querySelector('#text-area-in-react') 
    if(textarea){
      textarea.value = "This should be in state"

      const simChangeEvent = new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true });
      textarea.dispatchEvent(simChangeEvent);

     //when this runs I expect the react app to console.log the state, but it does not
    }
  }, 2000)
</script>
```

Any insights into this would be appreciated. Hopefully one or more of you out there will appreciate a crazy, hacky challenge.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After playing around with your example, I made it work with this code:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('#text-area-in-react')

var nativeTextAreaValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype, "value").set;
nativeTextAreaValueSetter.call(textarea, 'This should be in state');

const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
textarea.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This answer helped a lot:
[What is the best way to trigger onchange event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js)

Comment: Wow. Very interesting.

Comment: still useful 3 years later. cheers