# Rewriting JavaScript to React doesn't accept jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, url-rewriting

I am trying to re-write my old JavaScript code and make it work for React.

The main idea behind this is just including some external data to my 3rd party form.

This is my old JS:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
        portalId: 'myID',
        formId: 'myID',
        onFormSubmit: function() {
        jQuery('input[name="TICKET.content"]').val(JSON.stringify(window.cart,undefined, 2)).change();  
    }
});
</script>
```

And trying to make it work in React:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);

script.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (window.hbspt) {
        window.hbspt.forms.create({
            portalId: 'myID',
            formId: 'myID',
            onFormSubmit: function() {
                jQuery('input[name="TICKET.content"]').val(window.cart).change();
              },
            target: '#hubspotForm',
        });
    }
});
});

   <div id="hubspotForm"></div>
```

**Trying with react-hubspot-form**

```
    onSubmit={function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
   const ticket = document.querySelector('input[name="TICKET.content"]');
   const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(                                         window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,'value').set;
     nativeInputValueSetter.call(ticket, cart);
      const evt = new Event('change', {bubbles: true,});
      ticket.dispatchEvent(evt);}}
```

But with code above I am getting error of `jQuery` is not being defined. Is there better way how to re-write or am I able to define jQuery somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery?

You can use react setters [What is the best way to trigger onchange event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js/46012210)

Try

```
onFormSubmit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // I assume you do not want to submit
  const ticket = document.querySelector('input[name="TICKET.content"]');
  const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(ticket , window.cart);
  const evt = new Event('change', { bubbles: true});
  ticket.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan, how can I add this to onFormSubmit ?

Comment: try replacing `jQuery('input[name="TICKET.content"]').val(window.cart).change();` you have now with my code

Comment: See update  - I assume you need to not submit the form

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately after submitting the form I am having error in my console `The onFormSubmit function in hbspt.forms.create requires jQuery. It was not run.`, so it won't work.

Comment: Ah, then don't use hsforms

Comment: I unfortunately have to. I do not have any backend, so using 3rd parties. But thanks for try anyway!!

Comment: Then use a React version: https://www.google.com/search?q=hubspot+form+react

Comment: I also tried that already, but it gives `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`, so seems like the HubSpot form does  not like me at all.

Comment: I updated my post with react-hubspot-form attempt.

Comment: I actually misread your comment - I do need to submit the form, perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: So remove `e.preventDefault();` but since we do not know what the change event does, I cannot tell if that is enough