# Manually triggering onChange callback in React 18+

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem is that I'm unable to manually trigger onChange callback on input component in React. I have a custom 'file picker' which changes the input's value of new selected file path. I want to manually dispatch a 'change'/'input' event for this input.

Example case:

```html
<input onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} />
```

```js
const inputRef = /* ref of input above */

/* .. */
const newValue = 'path/test.ext';
inputRef.current.value = newValue;
// dispatch change event for inputRef.current to console log new value
```

I'd like to point out that I've already researched the subject. The newest solution I've could find is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71340077/14175627

Sadly, this solution **doesn't work anymore** and I'm unable to find working one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to trigger onchange event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js)

Comment: See the accepted answer to the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012210/9078341

Comment: Alternatively you can use [react-trigger-change](https://github.com/vitalyq/react-trigger-change)

Comment: The solution you gave I mentioned in the post. It doesn't work anymore in newest React version.