# Trigger onchange event of input in Reagent app

Tags: validation, input, clojurescript, reagent

How can I trigger the onchange event of a controlled input in a Reagent application?

```
[:input {:on-change (fn [e] ...) :id :my-input}]
```

Reagent implements React and the input components are Controlled React inputs so as I found out the input eventually doesn't have the on-change function. It has some kind of React property that contains the passed on-change function and the default on-change fn is nil in the input element object.

So therefore this doesn't working:

```
(let [input (.get-element-by-id js/document "my-input")]
     (.onchange input))
```

The purpose is that I have input fields and I want to make a field value validator that could be called anytime (e.g. clicking on a submit button). So I put the validator in the on-change function and it works well but now I need to call the on-change function if I want validate the fields when Im clicking on the submit button.

I tried this but nothing happened:

```
(defn input
  []
  (letfn [(f [] (let [e (js/Event. "change")
                      el (.getElementById js/document "my-input")]
                     (.dispatchEvent el e)))]
     [:<> [:input  {:id :my-input :on-change (fn [_] (println "Changed"))}]
          [:button {:on-click f} "Trigger on-change"]]))
```

Comment: It occurs to me that it may be possible to factor the validation out to be a pure function of something nice that you have access to both for live validation and for validation before submit. Then `:on-change` and submit could both call that function. --- firing the event looks like it might be a mess (dependent on the browser, react version, etc...)

Comment: I know at first look it seems difficult but I think there is a simple answer somewhere in the Universe. I chose this approach because the input component takes a field ID and a field props parameter and the field props map contains the validator function but the validate! event is a Re-Frame event and it doesnt get the field props map it only knows the field ID. So the Reagent component knows the validator function but the Re-Frame event doesn't and I really don't want to store the props map in a state atom in order to provide it for Re-Frame events.

Comment: Understood - I'm always looking for the functional answer. Here's a related question that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-change-or-input-event-in-react-js

Comment: I couldn't make it work so I put the code that I've just tried to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a bad idea, since the browser treats events triggered by the user differently than those triggered by code. So, you might find stuff work on the actual `:on-change` but not otherwise. Instead, just write a function to do what you want.

```clj
(defn stuff-i-want-to-happen [maybe with args] ...)

(defn input []
  [:<> [:input {:on-change (fn [_] (println "Changed") (stuff-i-want-to-happen 1 2 3)}]
       [:button {:on-click #(stuff-i-want-to-happen 4 5 6)} "Trigger on-change"]])
```

If you need to track additional state, you can just move that to the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose is that I have input fields and I want to make a field value validator that could be called anytime (e.g. clicking on a submit button).

Since you are using Reagent, I think what you want is to use form validator hooks.  You can rummage around npm but one I would suggest is [react hook form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form)

It does require you to learn their concept of "registering" a validation but it will be able to keep up with all of you validation needs (which only grow as real users get involved).