# Triggering a change or input event in a non-input ReactJS field

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to update the value of a `<figcaption>` field with the `textbox` role using Google Console. I've been able to update form fields using the solutions described in [What is the best way to trigger change or input event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-change-or-input-event-in-react-js)
, but this field just won't update. I'm able to set the text content of the element using `element.textContent = "mynewvalue"`, but that doesn't update the value the form value. I also tried looking through `element.__reactProps$...` and `element.__reactFiber$...` for events and using those to trigger updates, but no luck. The field works when I type in a value, so there must be a way to do this. What else can I try?